# How can I see the statistics for Google Photos links?

Tags: google-photos, goo.gl

When you share a link using **goo.gl**, it is possible to see the number and origin of clicks afterwards. When you share an album or a group of pictures by generating a link with Google Photos, the link looks like https://photos.app.goo.gl/xyz123abc (dummy values).

Since that seems to be also from goo.gl, is there any way to see the statistics related to those links?